# Error while updating Ubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I am a new user of Ubuntu..
What do I need to do to solve this update problem/bug?

```
W: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
W: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
W: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
W: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-proposed/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
W: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-proposed/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
W: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-proposed/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
E: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
slim@slim-N140:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are using an unsupported version of Ubuntu (Version 10.10)**.  You will have to install a supported version of Ubuntu to have your issues resolved.  You also are running the 32bit version.

The latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS doesn't have a normal 32 bit desktop installer.

If your computer doesn't support the 64 bit OS type, you will have to perform a workaround to install the latest 18.04 LTS version (which will be supported with updates for the next 5 years).

You can do this by creating a [32 bit mini iso installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), then perform updates and upgrades to move to a full desktop.

Alternatively you can install one of the older supported versions such as [Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), which has direct 32 bit desktop installer support.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will be supported for the next 3 years, and can be upgraded to the latest 18.04 LTS 32 bit version.

Comment: My pc doesn't support the 64 bit OS version so i have to install the 16.04 instead of 10.10 ?

Comment: You don't have to install 16.04, you can actually install 18.04 by creating the mini.iso installer linked in the answer.  I tested the install before I posted my answer.  It's a network installer.  The iso footprint is very small and will download in almost seconds.  When you boot to the mini.iso media, it'll give you a list of apps to install.  Checkmark Ubuntu-Desktop.  When the installer finishes I don't see a difference between the 32bit installation and the 64bit installation.

Comment: thank you james .. but didn't understand how to install a newer version with the .iso

Comment: There is an ISO.  It's linked in the answer.  Just burn the 32 bit mini iso installer linked in the answer and boot to it.  Answer the questions and proceed.  When you get to the part that asks you which components you want to install put a checkmark in **Ubuntu Desktop**.  It'll proceed with the install by downloading all the files.  The end results of the install would be a full Ubuntu 18.04 desktop installation.  I tested it just before posting the answer.  Give it a try, and ping me if you get stuck.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Maverick was version 10.10, released released on 10 October 2010, which is no longer supported. The current version, 18.04 LTS, will be supported until Avril 2023.

Comment: My pc doesn't support the 64 bit OS version so i have to install the 16.04 instead of 10.10 ?